# Use dynamic variable in SSIS to connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS Package that has an OLEDB/ADO.NET connection manager that connects to a SQL Server database.

I need to take the value of the connection string for this connection manager from a file located in a set place on the SSIS Machine.

I have created a variable called `CrmSqlConnectionString` that is initialized with a value of "example".

The first thing that runs in the package is a Script Task that loads the file and updates the variable to the correct connection string.

When I try to run it in Visual Studio I get the following exception:

> Error at Data Flow Task [ADO NET Source [16]]: ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection {GUID} with the following error message:
>   "Cannot open database "example" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'MAIN\name'.".
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: ADO NET Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC0208449. Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation. Error at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation. (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

I tried to set the DelayValidation property on the connection manager to true and I still get this error.

Does anyone have a solution for this situation?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the connection string you're using? Have you verified the string from the file is getting assigned to the variable correctly? How do you have the connection manager configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created connection manager with false connection data, and create an XML file located in my computer using Package Configuration.
Package Configuration helps me to config the connection string without throwing error.
recommend to use it if you need to set your connection string for two or more environments.

Answer (score 0):

DelayValidation property should be set to True on Data Flow Task. Not on the Connection Manager. This is exactly for this purpose.

Prototype is working on my PC. The picture below shows how it is set.

Comment: @EmmaV The dynamic variable you are using should contain properties of connection string, for example (InitialCatalog) rather than entire connect string. On the OLEDB connection manager properties click on the ... icon right of Expressions line and add a specific property. For example on my SSIS I was using to prototype it I added one property InitialCatalog that contains expression @[User::CmSqlConnectionString].